# Tool or IDEs that can generate dependency trees?

Tags: ide, dependency-management

Does anyone know of free tools, IDEs or plugins (preferably for Netbeans or Eclipse) that can generate dependency trees like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for Visual Studio? I am looking for one that does it for PHP, but ideally it would support multiple languages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can be coaxed into doing something similar.

Here is is: [GENERATE_TREEVIEW](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_generate_treeview).